# Join Conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

Hello I'm currently in a Intro to SQL in college. We are using Murach SQL Sever 2012 for Developers. I'm currently in Chapter 4 and I'm not understanding what a Join Condition is. I understand that is indicates how two tables should be compared, but what I can't understand is the syntax.

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, Vendor name
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
          ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID;
```

Why is it named `.VendorID`?

Sorry if this is vague.

Comment: But why do not you google some tutorial on this topic? - just write `SQL join  explanation` or something similar to google.

Comment: Why don't I just ask on here? Isn't the the point of this website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the join condition in sql by a linq query:

```
 var result =(from e in employee 
              join v in vendor where e.EmployeeId equals v.EmployeeId
              select new 
              {
                    EmployeeName = e.employeeName,
                    EmployeeSalary =e.employeeSalary,
                    VendorName = v.vendorName,
                    VendorDate =v.VendorDate,        
              }).ToList();
    return (result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Join clause combines records from two or more tables in a relational database.

**Example:**

If you have two table called `Vendors` and `Invoices`. Now, you are looking for common data between both table on the basis of id i.e. `VendorId`.

But, first of all, you need to access column of a table. So, you need to specify **which table** and **which column**. Then, it goes like `mytable.thiscolumn`.

Similarly, in your case you were trying to access `VendorId` column, which exist in both tables. So, you are explicitly telling, I need `VendorId` from the `Vendors` and `Invoices`.

Answer (score 1):

`VendorID` is the name of the column in tables `Vendors` and `Invoices`. For example if you had a table named `Event` and a column within that table is date, you could target that property by stating `Event.date`

Comment: So is it comparing the two tables to the VendorID?

Comment: It is comparing the VendorID value of tables `Vendors` and `Invoices`, ensuring that the id is (for example) `123` in both `Vendors` and `Invoices`. Display invoice number and vendor name only when the Vendor ID of the `Vendors` table is the same as the Vendor ID of the `Invoices` table.

Comment: OK I get it! I didn't know my databases had VendorID in both of them! Thank you so much!

Comment: VendorID is entirely arbritary property/column name that the designer/created of the database and its tables and columns decided. It could be named almost anything but you want to use descriptive column names. However you would need to use the column/property names that the database table is using otherwise you will receive errors and will not be able to access the data.

Comment: Please be sure to select one of the answers as best answer that helped you the most